# How does one specify the HTTP Request Method in the URL?

Tags: jsp, http, servlets, httprequest

I've just begun learning about Java Servlets, and in the process, I've had to go through the basics of how HTTP works. This had led me to some confusion.

I understand that methods like `doGet()` and `doPost()` are meant to respond to different kinds of HTTP Request Methods. There's a simple Tomcat project one of my senior colleagues has written that I'm using to understand how things work. In it, there's a JSP file with the following tag in it:

`<form action="dummyClass" method="post">`

So, I get how this specifies the HTTP Request Method to the Servlet from the HTML page. The user submits the form and the Servlet executes it's `doPost()` method.

But I can't understand how this would generalize to other kinds of resources on the server. I mean, HTTP is a general protocol for the web...it isn't specific to JSP. So how does typing a URL like `http://www.nowhere123.com/docs/index.html` into a browser specify to the server what HTTP Request Method I want to send it?

Comment: Yes , Reading it twice , lets see.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a URL into a browser address bar is always a GET (unless some really obscure browser I'm not aware of). You can do something similar with curl or wget and specify a method.

Answer (score 0):

When you type a URL in the browser address bar, it will perform a `GET` request.